# How to insert many sql rows into db with multiple mapped values to another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have two tables like this

Users:

```
id | username
-------------
1  | username1
2  | username2
```

Feed:

```
id | user1 | user2
------------------
1  | 1     | 2
```

I have a large array of feed values where user1 and user2 are usernames, and I want to map them to their corresponding id from the users table.

eg.

```
[ 
   { user1: "username1", user2: "username2" }
]
```

This seems simple enough if I have a single row and a single mapping (I can use a insert into select), but Its not clear how to batch (eg. `INSERT INTO feed (user1, user2) VALUES(1, 2), (3, 4)`) insert along with multiple mappings

Comment: "*I have a large array of feed values*" - Are these arrays found within a table? What's the source?

Comment: The source is a third party api. I have a table that contains an `id`, `username` mapping that I want to use to map the username value to the internal id value in the `users` table